# Django -- Empty database when inspectdb is used

Tags: python, database, django

I'm trying to follow the docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/legacy-databases/

First, I add the database to the settings.py, then I type

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

This is the output. I'm sorry this is so long; hopefully you only need to look at the big picture.

My problems are that

1) I don't know how to put something into the database (it's just random characters when I open the database with a text editor)

2) Nothing is output if I run python manage.py sqlcustom [app name]

3) Likely as a consequence of the above two, the imported database appears as empty in Django. When I type Bonds.objects.all() into the shell, it returns an empty list, when there should be plenty (I have confirmed that).

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
#
# Also note: You'll have to insert the output of 'django-admin.py sqlcustom [appname]'
# into your database.
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group'

class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    group_id = models.IntegerField()
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'

class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content_type_id = models.IntegerField()
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'

class AuthUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'

class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_groups'

class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'

class Bonds(models.Model):
    bond_id = models.TextField(blank=True)
    end_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    intr = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    base_i = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_id = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_pd = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'bonds'

class Combos(models.Model):
    type = models.TextField(blank=True)
    f_prop = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    f_start = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    f_end = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    b_prop = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    b_start = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    b_end = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    a_prop = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    a_start = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    a_end = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'combos'

class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.TextField(blank=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    change_message = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'

class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'

class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_session'

class DjangoSite(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_site'

class FxRates(models.Model):
    type = models.TextField(blank=True)
    fx_rate = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'fx_rates'

class NotendurDocument(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    docfile = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'notendur_document'

class Types(models.Model):
    type = models.TextField(blank=True)
    cal = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    ind = models.TextField(blank=True)
    paypy = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    loan_type = models.TextField(blank=True)
    adj_intr_date = models.NullBooleanField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'types'
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the rest of the directions? You need to add the output from `inspectdb` to a `models.py` file in one of your apps, then add that app to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Try the following:

### 1) Create an app

If you don't have an app you want to put the output from `inspectdb` into, just run `python manage.py startapp legacy`. This would create an app named `legacy` that you could sync up your existing database through.

### 2) Add inspectdb output to your app's models file

In the `models.py` file of your chosen app, paste the output from the `inspectdb` command. The easiest way to do this is probably to run `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`. This will create a file called `models.py` in the same directory that has `manage.py` and your app directories. Copy the output from that file into the `models.py` file in your app, i.e. in `legacy/models.py`.

### 3) Add your app to INSTALLED_APPS

In your `settings.py`, add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`. In this example, you'd want to add `'legacy',` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

### 4) Run syncdb

Run `python manage.py syncdb` to make sure all required tables are included. It looks like you already have those based on the output pasted above, but it won't hurt to run it again.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have done those steps, except that I just copy-pasted the output in the app.

Comment: Did you put it in the `models.py` file of the app?

Comment: Just noticed that some of your models are missing primary keys, which is required by Django. Not sure if that's your problem but try adding `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` to those models without a pk.

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately, the problem remains.

Comment: I'm guessing b/c adding that line doesn't actually change the db to add a pk. Can you edit this db? Maybe go into `sql` code and add a `pk` field for those models missing them, then run `inspectdb` again.

Comment: How do I edit it? I've made some meagre attempts, but the code inside is always a garbled mess.

Comment: What type of database are you using? Postgres, mySQL?

Comment: Oo that's a tougher one. You can't add a new primary key column to an existing table in SQLite.   Best bet is prob to remake table with new pk column and transfer old data over. Info on how to handle that is here: http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q11

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and it's an obvious one: Database routing. You need to create a `routers.py` file and add this to your `settings.py`:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp1.routers.name-of-your-routers.py-class',
                    'myapp2.routers.name-of-your-routers.py-class']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'myapp1': 'mydb1', 
                         'myapp2':'mydb2'}
```

Djangosnippets has the `routers.py` file: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2687/

You need do add an attribute called `in_db = 'desired-db'` in the Meta class of every class in your `models.py`.